# how to extract all integers from an array of random characters and transfer them to the array

Tags: java, arrays

, i do not know how to correctly write this code.

My code:

```
    String str = "23g32./'ef3";
    int[] arr = new int[str.length()];
    for (int digitsCount = 0; digitsCount < str.length(); digitsCount++)
        for (int digitsArrayIndex = 0; digitsArrayIndex < str.length(); digitsArrayIndex++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(digitsArrayIndex))) {
                arr[digitsArrayIndex] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(digitsArrayIndex)));
            }

        }
    System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

My output:

```
Array: [2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

I want:

```
Array: [2, 3, 3, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Don't use an array but a collection, e.g. `List<Integer>`. Then just call `add(Integer.parseInt(...))`. You're getting the current output because you're creating an array of integers with the exact same number of elements as the number of characters in the string and those elements will be initialized to 0.

Comment: instead of isDigit, try something like "0123456789".indexOf(char) != -1, or a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way would be just to use one loop, and another index.
When you have filled in the array, copy it using the value of the index

```
String str = "230g32./'ef3";
int index = 0;
int[] arr = new int[str.length()];
for (int digitsArrayIndex = 0; digitsArrayIndex < str.length(); digitsArrayIndex++) {
    if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(digitsArrayIndex))) {
        arr[index++] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(str.charAt(digitsArrayIndex)));
    }
}

System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(arr, index)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go more declarative and use Stream API for it:

```
  final List<Character> filteredCharacters = str.chars()
      .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
      .filter(Character::isDigit)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy approach here would be to just do a regex replacement on the input string to strip away any non digits.  Then, just use the character array from the resulting string.

```java
String str = "23g32./'ef3";
char[] output = str.replaceAll("\\D+", "").toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));  // [2, 3, 3, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Character.isDigit()`:

```
String str = "23g32./'ef3";
List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();

for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.isDigit(c)){
        digits.add(c - '0');
    }
}

System.out.println(digits);
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 3, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Never use obsolete `char`, use only code point integers.

```
 "23g32./'ef3".codePoints().filter( Character::isDigit ).map( Character::getNumericValue ).toArray()
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/6vmWmW).

> [2, 3, 3, 2, 3]

## Code points

The `char` type in Java is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode. Instead, learn to use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers.

The `String#codePoints` method returns an `IntStream`, that is, a stream of the code point integers, one for each character in your input string.

For each code point, ask if that character represents a digit as designated by the Unicode standard. If so, collect it. If not, ignore it.

Convert each of those digit characters into a number. Collect the numbers into your final array.

```java
int[] digits =
        "23g32./'ef3"
                .codePoints()
                .filter(
                        Character::isDigit
                )
                .map(
                        Character::getNumericValue
                )
                .toArray();
```

> digits = [2, 3, 3, 2, 3]

Often a `List` is more convenient than a mere array.

```java
List < Integer > digits =
        "23g32./'ef3"
                .codePoints()
                .filter(
                        codePoint -> Character.isDigit( codePoint )   // Or: Character::isDigit
                )
                .map(
                        codePoint -> Character.getNumericValue( codePoint )   // Or: Character::getNumericValue
                )
                .boxed()
                .collect( Collectors.toList() )   // Or, in Java 16+, simply `.toList()`
;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/6vmWmW).

> digits = [2, 3, 3, 2, 3]

Comment: @user15793316 Perhaps. But I've not quite grokked that [`Character.digit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#digit(int,int)) method. Perhaps [`Character. getNumericValue( codePoint )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(int))?

Comment: @user15793316 Thanks, fixed, using `Collectors.toList`.